# Mongodb upsert failing

Tags: mongodb

I have a following document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d2f6e83b6c835ebf12de33"),
    "name" : "john",
    "age" : 50,
    "places" : [ 
        "a", 
        "b", 
        "c"
    ],
    "orders" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "ordernumber" : 1,
            "price" : 100,
            "quantity" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "ordernumber" : "2",
            "price" : 1400.0000000000000000,
            "qty" : 10.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "ordernumber" : "2",
            "price" : 1400.0000000000000000,
            "qty" : 1.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "1",
            "ordernumber" : "2",
            "price" : 1400.0000000000000000,
            "qty" : 1.0000000000000000
        }
    ]
}
```

Issuing following update insert a new subdocument rather than just updating the document.Is something wrong with the query or does upsert works differently ?I tried by adding/removing id field of subdocument but it still doesnt work.What i am trying to do is to add order subdocument for the main document with name "john" and if an order does exist it gets updated.

```
db.mx1.update(
{"name":"john"},
{
    "$addToSet":{
        "orders":
        {
          "_id":"1",
            "ordernumber":"2",
            "price":1400,
            "qty":1
        }
    }
},
    {"upsert":"true"}
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

The [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator requires that the whole subdocument being added to the array only if it is unique, so you cannot consider it to be a *partial match* or *partial update*.

You could do that with the ["Bulk Operations API"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) as below

```
var bulk = db.mx1.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

// if we find the match order _id, update this order
bulk.find({name: 'john', 'orders._id': 1}).updateOne({
    {$set: {'orders.$': {_id: 1, ordernumber: '2', price: 1400, qty: 1}}}
});

// if we cannot find match order _id, insert the new one
bulk.find({name: 'john', 'orders._id': {$ne: 1}}).updateOne({ 
    {$addToSet: {orders: {_id: 1, ordernumber: '2', price: 1400, qty: 1}}}
});

bulk.execute();
```